# How to avoid composing  Where() operators in LINQ?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I'm working with LINQ and EF for the first time.   I've designed a db that links a Developer entity with a SkillProfile entity via a many to many entity named "DeveloperMatchesProfile".

The problem that I'm running into is that my LINQ query (which depends on using a navigational property off of the original range variable) needed an additional Where clause. This looks like it could turn inefficient quickly.   Is there a better way?   Does this construct pose a threat to performance?

[image: My Entities]

[image: My Query]

Comment: Where is the recursion supposed to be? Are you sure you're talking about recursion and not just a nested subquery or derived table?

Comment: You are correct it is simply a nested Where() - I will remove the misleading word from the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do something like this?

```
 var skills = _Context.DeveloperMatchesProfiles
      .Where(x => x.DeveloperId == developerId)
      .Select(x => x.SkillProfile);
```

You simply select the instances of DeveloperMatchProfiles with that developer Id and select the linked navigation property. You're basically going backwards, if I understand your relationships correctly.

Comment: The forehead slapping factor is great.   Thank you, Tejs.  :)

Answer (score 2):

> Does this construct pose a threat to performance?

There is no way to know that without acquiring the actual sql generated, and looking at the execution plan, execution time and IO.

> Is there a better way?

Might I recommend using `.Any()` over `.Count()` when testing for existence?

```
 _Context.SkillProfiles.Where(
  p => p.DeveloperMatchesProfiles.Any(d => d.DeveloperId == developerId)
);
```